# KATALON File upload and send keys doesn't work on NEW angular drag and drop form

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, uploading, katalon-studio

For most of the uploads I just used `SendKeys` or `upload file` method
but this page will not take it. 
https://www.clientconnections.com/Account/SignUp
Manually you drop a file and get a popup to approve

I tried  the following 2 ways

```
WebUI.uploadFile(findTestObject('For deleteing/Page_Candidate Sign up/cc-resume-upload'), 'U:\\Resume For Test.docx')
```

and

```
WebUI.sendKeys(findTestObject('For deleteing/Page_Candidate Sign up/cc-resume-upload'), 'U:\\Resume For Test.docx')
```

The page is Open to the world so can anyone figure this out? and reply with the script.

Comment: OK Found an answer in the below link, and some dev help.  Had to create an object for the class = resume-file-upload (this is the input)  and link that Object via the Shadow Root Parent cc-resume-upload

https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/shadow_dom_elements_testing.html#automate-testing-shadow-dom-with-katalon-studio

Comment: Did you consider writing your comment as an answer, so it can get more attention?